# Difference of menu and theme_location

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a menu by `wp_nav_menu()`, there are two argument seems the same although the name are different: `menu` and `theme_location`. Assume I already register a menu and the name/id is `nice`, now I want to display the menu on a page by `wp_nav_menu()`, this is what I do:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
   'menu' => 'nice',
   'theme_location' => 'nice'
) );
```

If I don't specify the `theme_location`, it will still work? Because I already tell wordpress the menu I wanna display, and vice versa, if I specify the theme location, why do I still need to specify `menu` which I wanna use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu` and `theme_location` has some explanations, menu is for specific menu id, slug, name or object where you will show that specific menu by the menu id, slug, name or object, on the other hand `theme_location` is where you want to show your menu. It is not necessary to set the `menu` and `theme_location` at a time, but if you set two options at a time it will priority the `menu` first then `theme_location`, in case you have no menu with that name/slug then it will check the `theme_location`, in case you set a wrong `theme_location` which is actually not registered then it will call the `fallback_cb`. Note that menu name comes from the admin panel https://prnt.sc/j-m6B-jY252k where `theme_location` comes from the functions.php file where you registered the menu https://prnt.sc/BglTqU_xows2 . This `theme_location` will show in the menu area in the admin panel https://prnt.sc/KY7cYottkJWe . So, in conclusion, you can use any one of it for showing the menu but it is totally up to you which way you will choose, but for developers it is wise to set `theme_location` instead of menu.
I have tried to explain everything from my end but if you have more questions you can read the official details of menu [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)